# On browser back php code is not executed

Tags: php, browser

On browser back php code is not executed in login.
Steps
there 2 webpage lets call x and y user can login from any of page either x or y
1.currently user is on x page
2.user navigate to y page and do login
3.user click on browser back button and came to x page
4.on x page it does not show login.
5.once i refreshed x page it start showing login

why this happens i am storing login values in session.

thank u

Comment: When you hit the "back" button you are going back to the previous page, but also back in time to how it looked like when you were there. This is default browser behaviour and there's good reasons for not overriding it unless you really have to. In this particular case just redirect the user to the home page so they can't go back via the browser button.

Answer (score 0):

The back() method loads the previous URL in the history list. This is the same as clicking the "Back button" in your browser, or history.

Just refresh the page by going directly to index.php

Comment: I think you misunderstood what the question is about. `back()` is a method that, as you said, does the same as clicking the back-button for the browser. However, OP asked by his PHP code wasn't executed the way I thought it would (and I believe the reason lies in how cookies are dealed with).

Comment: If he's even using cookies or a SESSION. We aren't getting a lot of information so not much we can do, I assumed he was wondering why new php wasn't being executed

Comment: Like you said, *We aren't getting a lot of information*, which means that the question would be very hard to answer in a good manner, so one should perhaps avoid answering it? ;-)

Comment: thnks for answer guys but issue is still unresolved case is i have 2 webpages and user can login any of page suppose user navigate to 2nd page and do login and click back button in browser he will cme to 1st page and this point he should see he is login to the system and this is not happning but once i refresh that page it shows login .sry if u guys had difficulty in understanding my question